# Delay in playing video which is obtained from Wowza streaming engine

Tags: ios, video, streaming, wowza, m3u8

When I am playing back the video which is running in **`wowza`** streaming engine

(i.e when I am trying to load the url 
http://192.168.10.55:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8 using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` it is playing fine. But there is more than 30 seconds delay in playing video.

Please help me to avoid this delay time.

Comment: i dont think this is an issue from iOS development side please contact to the service provider.

Comment: Yeah I agree with Nitin, one more thing is to download the file and load it. Try `AVPlayer`, not sure whether this will reduce the delay.

Comment: It is a live streaming and I have also tried with `AVPlayer` but it also getting delay

Comment: check Brads answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515695/how-can-i-reduce-latency-in-hls-streaming-with-wowza)

Answer (score 0):

Delays are normal in HLS streaming and can occur on player side where there is usually some buffer, but the chunking nature of HLS also requires some delay. You can lower the chunk size in Wowza config to 3 seconds if you want. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reduce latency under 10s by adjusting settings as documented at https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?88-How-to-configure-Apple-HLS-packetization-(cupertinostreaming)#mgrlive :

> Cupertino segmenter property reference
>
> cupertinoChunkDurationTarget - Sets the duration of each chunk in
>   milliseconds. If you're using Origin/Edge configuration this will need
>   to be set on the Origin and Edges with matching values.
>
> cupertinoMaxChunkCount - Sets the maximum number of chunks stored in
>   the available chunk list.
>
> cupertinoPlaylistChunkCount - Sets the number of items returned in the
>   playlist.
>
> cupertinoRepeaterChunkCount - Sets the number of chunks that are
>   immediately sent from the origin to the edge after initial connection
>   and is configured on the origin. This property is only required for
>   use with Live Edge applications. A live edge application will have a
>   StreamType of liverepeater-edge in the Application.xml file.

Try with smaller chunks (2000ms) and low chunk count to reduce possible latency.